# Please explain why this happens?

Tags: javascript

can someone explain to me why i get 1 output when i don't pass arguments in the function and also when i pass arguments i get 120 twice.

```js
let n = 5;
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function multiply(arr, n) {
    let product = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        product *= arr[i];
        console.log(product);
    }
    return product;
}

console.log(multiply(arr, n));
```

```js
let n = 5;
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function multiply(arr, n) {
    let product = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        product *= arr[i];
        console.log(product);
    }
    return product;
}

console.log(multiply());
```

Comment: You are returning the `var product = 1;` variable

Comment: Step through it with a debugger (or pen and paper) and see how often the `console.log(product);` inside the loop is executed respectively.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". The current title summarizes about 10% of the questions we get in JavaScript :).

Comment: In the case of the double 120 it is because you are using `console.log()` within your loop but also to show the final result with ` console.log(multiply(arr,n));`. In the case of the output 1, it is because you are directly returning `product` which value is "1"

Comment: "*when i don't pass arguments in the function*" - better use `multiply(arr, 0)`, which will behave the same but use more sensible values

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not passing the `arr`, and `n` arguments in the second case, they are `undefined`. So the for loop never runs, and hence the value of product remains as it is, which is returned back by the function, as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You get 120 twice when you pass values as you are logging the value inside of the for loop, and then returning the final value(120) and also logging that to the console.

When you don't pass values, your function sets product to 1, skips over the loop as there is no number to compare i to, and then returns product (1) to be outputted to the console

Answer (score 0):

When no `n` is provided, the condition in the loop `i < n` becomes `i < undefined` which will always return false. Therefore, the function in the second example will return the value of `product` without modifying it in the `for` loop.

```js
let i = 0,
    n = undefined;
console.log(i < n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your internal printing (logging) from your final result at the end.

If you do not pass an array into your function, you will get a null-pointer error. If you do not pass a number in for the second parameter, your loop will never do anything. You need to pass in both, or fall-back to the array length.

You can bake `Error` calls into your function to prevent any unexpected behavior.

```js
const n = 5;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function multiply(arr, n) {
  if (arr == null) throw new Error('arr cannot be null!');
  if (arr.length === 0) throw new Error('arr cannot be empty!');
  if (arguments.length < 2 || n == null) n = arr.length;
  let product = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    product *= arr[i];
    console.log(`arr[${i}] = ${arr[i]} | ${product}`);
  }
  return product;
}

const product = multiply(arr, n); // You are printing inside...

console.log(`Product = ${product}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you've declared the `product` as `1`
while you're calling your function without any parameters

```
multiply()
```

You're not passing any value for your variable `arr` and `n` so the loop never runs and as you've defined your `Product` variable as `1` so it `returns 1` in the `console.log()`